# How and Where does the official docker image of postgreSQL persist its database

Tags: postgresql, docker, persistence, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and a bit confused as I was expecting my PostgreSQL docker container not to be able to persist any data, but when I spin it back up after stopping it, my database data still seems to be there.

I've been looking around for existing answers and found the following on stack exchange:
*(Sorry, I don't have the rep to post more than 2 links)*

- Docker postgres persistance and container lifetime
- How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres
- How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in docker

But I still don't understand.  Maybe someone could spell it out a bit more obviously for me!  This is what I did:

*(The docker compose and build files I used are shown at the bottom of this post)*
I followed the tutorial from the Docker documentation site:
[Quickstart: Docker Compose and Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)
Which all worked perfectly so I went on to follow the Django app tutorial:
[Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)
Again all good, so I played around on my new web site for a bit, causing the database to get populated with some data.

I can see how the web app code for my example Django app sticks around since it's mounted on a volume on my host, and also copied into the image that gets built when I run docker-compose again **but I expected any data stored in the postgres database container to be lost after stopping all the containers.**  However after stopping all my running containers I went back to my docker project directory and ran:

```
docker-compose up
```

And it all came straight back up and my data from the previous run of the images was all still there in the database and used in my Django web app.

So what's going on?

1. Where is the database storing it's data?

   - Somewhere on the host?
   - How can I find out where that is?
2. How is the postgres container managing to persist data across separate runs?

   - Which part of the build files makes that happen?
   - Or is this somehow default behaviour for the official postgres image?

Below are the build files I used as directed by the docker quickstart tutorial referenced above.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

requirements.txt

```
Django
psycopg2
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored inside the docker container. The container still keeps all its data when you stop it. You will lose the data only if you remove it:

```
docker rm <container>
```